# mod_rewrite migration from apache to lighttpd

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

how to describe the same thing with lighttpd?

my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style\.css|image|image-small|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_rewrite"
)

$HTTP["host"] == "web.com" {

    server.document-root = "/var/www/web.com/public_html/"

    url.rewrite-once = ( 
      "^(?!index\.php|style\.css|image|image-small|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|favicon\.ico)" => "$0"
      "^(.*)" => "index.php"
    )

}
```

More info [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/MigratingFromApache)